# How to use neo4j bolt session/transaction in a procedure as plugin for neo4j server extension?

Tags: neo4j

1. How to handle multiple session in a single procedure for sample sudo code is presented below?
2. I tried the same code below but for some reason it doesn't work in as plugin, with the neo4j/plugin...really don't know what happens. [BUT WORKS WELL WITH IN ECLIPSE]

   ```java
   @Procedure("test.begin")
   public void begin() throws InterruptedException {
       Driver driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost/",
               Config.build().withEncryptionLevel(Config.EncryptionLevel.NONE).toConfig());
       Session session = driver.session();

       System.out.println("............started");
       String query ="";
       if (true) {
           try (Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction()) {
               int count = 10000;
               for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                   Thread.sleep(1);   // some conversion
                    query = "create(n:Person{name:'" + i + "'})";
                   tx.run(query);
               }
               System.out.println("first innerloop");
               tx.success();
           }
       }
       if (true) {
           try (Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction()) {
               int count = 10000;
               for (int p = 0; p < count; p++) {
                   Thread.sleep(1);
                    query =  "create(n:Person{name:'" + p + "'})";;
                   tx.run(query);
               }
               System.out.println("second innerloop");
               tx.success();
           }
       }

       if (true) {
           try (Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction()) {
               int count = 70000;
               while (count > 0) { /// here this has 1million records
                   for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
                       Thread.sleep(2);
                        query =  "create(n:Person{name:'" + j + "'})";;
                       tx.run(query);
                   }
                   System.out.println("third innerloop");
                   count--;
               }
               tx.success();
           }


       }
       session.close();
       driver.close();
   }
   ```

Comment: You seem to have several typos in your code snippet (e.g., several missing "{" characters), some of which should not allow the code to compile. Can you show your actual code?

Comment: Yes please...i have updated.....increment loop to 1 million. and check

Comment: You don't describe what the issue **is**. Are we supposed to run your code to see it? Also, you don't need to use the driver in a procedure, as it's running within Neo4j. Get the `GraphDatabaseService` injected, as in the [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#writing-procedure): see the use of `@Context`.

Comment: I created a jar regular jar NOT runnable jar. When I run it as plugin in neo4j. I get GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for 831ms. In the community version...3.0.4.. any setting I have to do on the JAR or in .neo.conf file? Should it be a runnable jar?

Comment: I said nothing about a runnable jar, I'm just saying the code of the procedure is executed within the same JVM as Neo4j, which is why the procedure doesn't need a driver to connect to Neo4j: it's **inside Neo4j**. By the way, use a mention (@...) when replying to a comment or the other person isn't notified.

Comment: @FrankPavageau, I tried injecting GraphDataService as well, when the operation was slow, i moved to driver. I was just check the difference. Well if any body could answer my question on kind of JAR and how to properly use transaction for creating constraints, indexes and nodes in a single procedure. That would be great. This question is related to to it. as you I encountered timeout issues or DB crash. Hence each if is performing either constraints, indexes or adding nodes.

Comment: A regular jar is all it takes. The more nodes you try to create, the longer it will take, it's normal that creating a million nodes takes a while. You also need to limit the size of the transaction or you risk running into OutOfMemory errors, which means you have to batch: open a transaction, create a number of nodes (like 10000), commit the transaction, repeat. There's no timeout in a procedure, you don't have a remote connection.