# How to create a constraints, indexes and nodes in a single procedure/plugin call?

Tags: neo4j

similarly the code is for creating indexes and millions of nodes the respective methods. This is for creating fresh DB from JSON file.

I encounter the following error:

1. Exception: Cannot perform data updates in a transaction that has performed schema updates. Simple begin transaction and close it doesn't work?
2. After some time the session crashes in CreateNodes() method?
3. How exactly we separate the schema creation and data update?
4. Also refer the question I have posted before trying to get the similar answer, but no success. (I tried both injecting GraphDatabaseService as well as with Bolt Driver the result is the same).
   [How to use neo4j bolt session/transaction in a procedure as plugin for neo4j server extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39480552/how-to-use-neo4j-bolt-session-transaction-in-a-procedure-as-plugin-for-neo4j-ser)

```java
for (int command = 4; command < inputNeo4jCommands.size(); command++) {

    log.info(inputNeo4jCommands.get(command));
    NEO4JCOMMANDS cmnd = NEO4JCOMMANDS.valueOf(inputNeo4jCommands.get(command).toUpperCase());
    log.info(NEO4JCOMMANDS.valueOf(inputNeo4jCommands.get(command).toUpperCase()).toString());

    if (NEO4JCOMMANDS.CONSTRAINT.equals(cmnd)) {
        CreateConstraints1();
    }

    if (NEO4JCOMMANDS.INDEX.equals(cmnd)) {
        CreateIndexes();
    }

    if (NEO4JCOMMANDS.MERGE.equals(cmnd)) {
        log.info("started creating nodes........");

        CreateNodes();
    }
}
```

```java
private void CreateIndexes1() {

    log.info("Adding indexes.....");
    log.info("into started adding index ......");
    try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {
        log.info("got a transaction .....hence started adding index ......");
        Iterator<Indx> itIndex = json2neo4j.getIndexes().iterator();

        while (itIndex.hasNext()) {
            Indx indx = itIndex.next();
            Label lbl = Label.label(indx.getLabelname());

            Iterable<IndexDefinition> indexes = db.schema().getIndexes(lbl);
            if (indexes.iterator().hasNext()) {
                for (IndexDefinition index : indexes) {
                    for (String key : index.getPropertyKeys()) {
                        if (!key.equals(indx.getColName())) {
                            db.schema().indexFor(lbl).on(indx.getColName());
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                db.schema().indexFor(lbl).on(indx.getColName());

            }
            tx.success();
            tx.close();
        }
        log.info("\nIndexes Created..................Retured the method call ");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of context is missing from your question and code examples, so it's hard to give a definite answer. Where is the exception thrown in the code example? There's no `CreateNodes()` method, so we can't find out why it's failing (Out Of Memory Error due to a transaction too large?).

However, there's an issue with your transaction management in the `CreateIndexes1()` method (not following the Java naming conventions, by the way):

```java
try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {
    // ...
    while (/* ... */) {
        // ...
        tx.success();
        tx.close();
    }
}
```

You're closing the transaction multiple times, when it's actually in a try-with-resources block where you don't need to close it yourself *at all*:

```java
try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {
    // ...
    while (/* ... */) {
        // ...
    }
    tx.success();
}
```

I guess `json2neo4j` is the deserialization of a JSON describing the indices to create on labels. The logic is flawed: you try to create an index for a property as soon as you find an index for another property, when you should find out if an index for the current property exists and only create the index if it's missing then.

```java
for (Indx indx : json2neo4j.getIndexes()) {
    Label lbl = Label.label(indx.getLabelname());

    boolean indexExists = false;
    for (IndexDefinition index : db.schema().getIndexes(lbl)) {
        for (String property : index.getPropertyKeys()) {
            if (property.equals(indx.getColName())) {
                indexExists = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (indexExists) {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!indexExists) {
        db.schema().indexFor(lbl).on(indx.getColName());
    }
}
```

Comment: @Frank........There are only 2 constraints and 2 indexes from the JSON file. So, it not huge as of now. More over, I had done this on a fresh database, there are not indexes or constraints.........Could please tell me which one of reply answers this question..."Exception: Cannot perform data updates in a transaction that has performed schema updates. Simple begin transaction and close it doesn't work?" ......I get this error even on a blank database.........thanks.

Comment: Regarding the reply on Transaction management convention. I tried all the possible combination on tx.success() and tx.close()........I tried removing it all together.  That's why I had requested on....... How to use constraints, indexes and nodes in the single procedure.....with getting this error "Exception: Cannot perform data updates in a transaction that has performed schema updates. Simple begin transaction and close it doesn't work?"..........Please if can upload a sample that explain how to execute all the 3 commands in a single procedure.

Comment: Using the stack trace of the exception, you can find out where it's occurring in your code, which would be a start. Maybe reading the indices counts as a "data update" and you need to split the code in 2 steps: find out which indices need to be created in a first transaction, create the missing ones (and nothing else) in a second.

Comment: Alternatively, create a [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) someone else can use to reproduce the problem without writing it all by themselves. I'm not going to create a Maven project, develop a procedure doing something like yours and deploy it to a Neo4j instance just to find out what's going wrong, and I doubt someone else is. Push something to GitHub for example. And isolate questions, because you seem to be chasing multiple bugs at once.